# React reusable components which method is better to use

Tags: reactjs

I want to make some reusable components like modal, autocomplete, popover, etc. But I don t know which approach is better when is about the state

1. keep the state in redux - the disadvantage that I see in redux is that I must to create a reducer foreach place where I'm using the modal(example)
2. keep the state in parent component - the disadvantage is that when for example I press the button to open the modal will re render parent + children.
3. keep the state in the component - the disadvantage is that I must to pass everytime the button like props.

Which approach is better? I'm beginner I don't know if this is a dumb question to ask. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to look at any other UI libraries?

Comment: Could you provide some more information, like a concrete example of what you're trying to achieve? There is not one right answer for all. It depends on the use case.

Comment: @Vash Like UI library I'm using material-ui